# Php function strpos does not always find "the needle"

Tags: php, strpos

I use strpos to find if a certain expression (in my case exception) is contained in a response I receive from API. However, sometimes it seems that the Exception message passes by this function. Is this at all possible?

```
$response = $this->curlRequest($uri, $authHeader);

if (strpos(strtoupper($response), 'APIEXCEPTION') !== false) { 
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: may be is $response UNICODE? than try to use `mb_strpos` function

Comment: Is `$response` instance of ?? `string` ? try to do this `strtoupper((string) $response, ...)`

Comment: Yes, $response is a string

Comment: @Bukharov Sergey , it is possible that this is the problem, as the $response has some strange characters added. So with mb_strpos does the encoding parameter hold the encoding I want to use (the one use by the Needle)?

Comment: @Bukharov That would have to be a pretty uncommon encoding in which the string "APIEXCEPTION" is not the same as in virtually all other encodings… And "Unicode" is not an encoding, *UTF-16* would be (and yes, UTF-16 would be an example of where it would actually fail).

Comment: @Dimentica I doubt the server randomly changes its character encoding. You'll have to provide a sample of the actual response you receive, otherwise we can't help a lot.

Comment: @deceze the response which I want to catch is "&#8220;TranslateApiException: The Azure Market Place Translator Subscription associated with the request credentials has zero balance. : ID=3832.V2_Json.Translate.4385FFCE&#8220;"

Comment: Well, if that's the actual response you're getting, then this should work just fine. You'll have to give us a sample which *fails.*

Comment: Out of question but you can use `stripos` instead of needing `strtoupper`. Now I agree that you should give an example of $response which fails because your test is correct.
`if (stripos($response, 'APIEXCEPTION') !== false) {`

Comment: Works for me, with that response: https://3v4l.org/efSjQ